# What's wrong with my stat() function in C in linux

Tags: c, linux, stat

I'm trying to list file infos(including directories etc) using stat()

It works fine when I give "."(current directory) as argv[1] (ex. $./a.out .)

but has an error when I give other directory such as "..", "/" etc.

stat function returns -1(fail) when after direntp points ".."(parent directory).

here's an example.

```
$ ls -a ..
. .. sample temple

$ ./a.out ..
Success: .
Success: ..
Fail: sample
Stat Call Error.
Terminate.

$
```

So why does it fail when I give other path to argument of stat()?

here's my code below

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "dirent.h"
#include "sys/stat.h"
#include "unistd.h"
#include "stdlib.h"

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    DIR *dirp;
    struct dirent *direntp;
    struct stat statbuf;

    dirp = opendir(argv[1]);
    while((direntp = readdir(dirp)) != NULL)
    {
        if(direntp->d_ino == 0)
            continue;
        if(direntp->d_name[0] != '.'); /* doesn't matter, This isn't a mistake */
        {
            if(stat(direntp->d_name, &statbuf) == -1)
            {
                printf("Fail: %s\n", direntp->d_name);
                printf("Stat Call Error\n");
                exit(-1);
            }
            printf("Success: %s\n", direntp->d_name);
        }
    }
    closedir(dirp);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `if(stat(direntp->d_name, &statbuf) d_name);` : does that compile?

Comment: I fixed code. left bracket was omitted cuz it is regarded as a tag in html, so I changed to == -1

Comment: `if(direntp->d_name[0] != '.');` means that everything after that line runs without regard to the value of `direntp->d_name[0]`

Comment: `doesn't matter, This isn't a mistake` No it isn't a syntax error, but it is effectively a no-op and complete nonsense. (and you should not exit on stat() faulre but just continue (Because of race conditions, for instance))

Answer (score 3):

The `opendir` function returns directory contents using *relative* path, not absolute.

When you're not scanning the current directory, you only have the name of the entry, but not its full path, so `stat` fails on all entries because it looks them up in the current directory (but `.` and `..` which also exist in the current directory).

Of course it works in the current directory, where you don't have this problem.

Fix: compose the full pathname, ex like this:

```
char fp[PATH_MAX];
snprintf(fp, sizeof(fp), "%s/%s", argv[1], direntp->d_name);
if(stat(fp, &statbuf)) {
...
```